# TableSort for multiple languages

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable, tablesorter

I am working on a table that will contain data, and what I should be able to do is sort the data by using the columns, so by clicking the columns it will order the data alphabetically and so on. To achieve this need I came across [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jquery library, which works absolutely fine when sorting English alphabetic characters.

However the problem I am encountering is that I will have multiple tables, where each table will contain data only for a specific country on a specific language from a range of 60 countries, so I should be fine with English/Latin Characters, but I am encountering problem when dealing with Russian, Chinese, Japanese and other languages, does anyone know a quick work around that may help me in this occasion.

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html), you can set the [`textSorter` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#textsorter) to use alternative sorting algorithms. Specifically, [here is a demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-custom-sort.html) that sorts the Icelandic alphabet using the [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com/arrays#sorting) array sort.

```
$(function() {
  // define sugar.js Icelandic sort order
  Array.AlphanumericSortOrder = 'AaÁáBbCcDdÐðEeÉéĘęFfGgHhIiÍíJjKkLlMmNnOoÓóPpQqRrSsTtUuÚúVvWwXxYyÝýZzÞþÆæÖö';
  Array.AlphanumericSortIgnoreCase = true;
  // see https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar/issues/382#issuecomment-41526957
  Array.AlphanumericSortEquivalents = {};

  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',
    ignoreCase : false,
    textSorter : {
      1 : Array.AlphanumericSort, // alphanumeric sort from sugar
    }
  });
});
```

For languages like Russian, Chinese & Japanese, you'll need to modify the `Array.AlphanumericSortOrder` variable for that language.